# How to import a method in another groovy script in to my script and also can i import from another jar?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, groovy, jar

I have a shared lib ".jar" which has a few classes in it with some methods. Is there a way in groovy that I can import those classes from a jar and use the methods in them Please do let me know (If this is not possible please answer my next question below.)

I have a CommonScript.groovy file which has common code/methods. Now how can I import and use those methods, in my currentScript.groovy file.

Thank you in advance.

few details than you might be looking for are

1. I'm using maven
2. Shared Library is not in my repo

Comment: are you using maven to compile script? In any case import works in groovy just like in java..

Comment: Yes using Maven however I tried but I'm not able to use those methods in the shared library.

Comment: Could you provide more details in your question? The groovy code, project organization, error, ...